# TypeError: http is not a function in Jest framework

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, pact

I am using React.js as my JavaScript framework, where I have installed Jest and using pact (CDC) for unit test cases and while I run the command `npm run test` the spec.js file is failing and throwing an error like this

> TypeError: http is not a function

This is `criteria-managementcomponent.spec.js` file

```
const path = require('path')
const pact = require('pact')
const API_PORT =  process.env.API_PORT || 9123
const {
  fetchProviderData, getCriteriaManagementComponent, criteriaManagementComponent
} = require('../client')

// Configure and import consumer API
// Note that we update the API endpoint to point at the Mock Service
const LOG_LEVEL = process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'WARN'

const provider = pact({
  consumer: 'Web Login',
  provider: 'Web API',
  port: API_PORT,
  log: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'logs', 'pact.log'),
  dir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'pacts'),
  logLevel: LOG_LEVEL,
  spec: 2
})

describe('Started Testing Pact', () => {

  beforeEach((done) => {
    return provider.setup().then(() => done());
  });

  afterEach((done) => {
    return provider.finalize().then(() => done())
  })

  describe('criteriaManagement', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      let criteriaManagement = {
        uponReceiving: 'wrong criteriaManagement',
        state: 'Code OK',
        withRequest: {
          method: 'GET',
          path: '/api/criteria',
        },
        willRespondWith: {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
          },
          body: {

                code: "string",
                context: {},
                message: "string",
                payload: [
                  {
                    country: "string",
                    createdBy: "string",
                    displayOrder: 0,
                    id: "string",
                    lastModifiedBy: "string",
                    name: "string",
                    translations: {},
                    warehouse: "string"
                  }
                ]      
          }
        }
      };
      return provider.addInteraction(criteriaManagement)
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      return provider.verify()
    })

    it('Login test', done => {
      criteriaManagementComponent().then((res) => {
        expect(res.code).not.toBeNull();
        expect(res.context).toBeDefined();
        expect(res.message).not.toBeNull();
        expect(res.payload.country).not.toBeNull();
        expect(res.payload.createdBy).not.toBeNull();
        expect(res.payload.displayOrder).toBe(0);
        expect(res.payload.id).not.toBeNull();
        expect(res.payload.lastModifiedBy).not.toBeNull();
        expect(res.payload.translations).toBeDefined();
        expect(res.payload.name).not.toBeNull();
        expect(res.payload.warehouse).not.toBeNull();


      });
      done();
    })
  });
})
```

This is client.js file for `criteria-managementcomponent.spec.js` file

```
const request = require('superagent')
const API_HOST = process.env.API_HOST || 'http://localhost'
const API_PORT = process.env.API_PORT || 9123
const API_ENDPOINT = `${API_HOST}:${API_PORT}`

// Fetch provider data
const fetchProviderData = (submissionDate) => {
  return request
    .get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/provider`)
    .query({ validDate: submissionDate })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("Response :: ", res.body);
      return {
        count: 100 / res.body.count,
        date: res.body.date
      }
    })
}

const getCriteriaManagementComponent = (accessToken, expiresIn) => {
  return request
    .post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/criteria`)
    .then((res) => {
      return {
        code : res.body.code
      }
    })
}

const criteriaManagementComponent = () => {
    // const request = require('request')
  console.log("End Point =========> ", `${API_ENDPOINT}/api/criteria`)
  return request.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/criteria`).then((res) => {
    return {
      code : res.body.code,
      context:res.body.context,
      message:res.body.message,
      payload:res.body.payload,
      profile:res.body.payload.profile,

      successful : res.body.successful
    }
  })
};

module.exports = {
  fetchProviderData, getCriteriaManagementComponent, criteriaManagementComponent
}
```

Comment: Hello @halfer
i have written the file name in caps to highlite the file name, its all in lower case as it should be :)

Comment: i have read the link what you sent me and thats so kind of you to correct me as its not the right way. yes...! i will remove those lines from the question :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know where things are going wrong without a line number in the stack trace, however one thing is for certain - you're using a very old version of pact.

You should be using `@pact-foundation/pact` now.

As for the `http` issue, is it possible you have any mocks setup that are interfering? The issue seems unrelated to pact.

Lastly, if you could provide a reproducible github repo that others could download and run, you could probably get even better help.